# Extract the amounts(t0, t1) per tick from Uniswap v3 Pool

Tags: uniswap, polygon, uniswapv3

I want to be extract the amounts of t0 and t1 from a Uniswap v3 Pool.

I was trying with some method which I found on other post, but I think is not working, or I am doing something wrong.

This is the method tried by me:

```
function extractAmounts(){
            
    const tick = -282260;
    const liquidity = 31494343572914561514 //liquidityNet
    const sqrtPriceCurrent = 58884551862568005367467
                
    const sqrtPriceLow = Math.pow(1.0001, -282260);
    const sqrtPriceHigh = Math.pow(1.0001, -282250);
                
    const sp = Math.max(Math.min(sqrtPriceCurrent, sqrtPriceHigh), sqrtPriceLow)
                
    const amount0 = liquidity * (sqrtPriceHigh - sp) / (sp * sqrtPriceHigh)
    const amount1 = liquidity * (sp - sqrtPriceLow)
                
    console.log(amount0, amount1)
                
}
extractAmounts();
```

The values printed in console for the tick(wrote manually by me) are not matching with the chart from Uniswap page (`USDC locked value`, in the image):

https://info.uniswap.org/#/polygon/pools/0xa374094527e1673a86de625aa59517c5de346d32
[image]
*The values from the image is for example, and is not matching the values from code.*

Someone can explain to me how to calculate the amounts for a tick(current/specific one)?

A pool example(polygon): https://polygonscan.com/address/0xa374094527e1673a86de625aa59517c5de346d32#readContract

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [LiquidityAmounts#getAmountsForLiquidity function](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/b13f9d9d9868b98b765c4f1d8d7f486b00b22488/contracts/libraries/LiquidityAmounts.sol#L120)? It should be pretty straightforward to implement this function in java using the java.math.BigInteger type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an NPM library that does all these calculations. It's called univ3prices: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@thanpolas/univ3prices/v/3.0.2

Specifically, check univ3prices.getAmountsForCurrentLiquidity (gets amounts for the current tick space) and univ3prices.getAmountsForLiquidityRange (gets amounts for an arbitrary range)

If you are looking for the exact math, it could be found here:
see section 3.3.3 in this whitepaper: [atiselsts.github.io/pdfs/uniswap-v3-liquidity-math.pdf](http://atiselsts.github.io/pdfs/uniswap-v3-liquidity-math.pdf)

Comment: The idea is that I am coding in different language(java), and I don't find any SDK for java from Uniswap. So, I need to implement it by myself, but I can't understand how the calculations are made.

Comment: check section 3.3.3 in this whitepaper: https://atiselsts.github.io/pdfs/uniswap-v3-liquidity-math.pdf . It has all the math

Comment: Can you add the comment into the answer? To accept it as solution?

Comment: done. thank you